# Angular Material Form Style - Input Background and Button Height

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a pretty basic form of an e-mail input and submit button.  I'm trying to do the following:

- Have the e-mail input background be white
- Have the Submit button be the same height as the input

When I try to change the background of the input in CSS, it only changes a small rectangle within the Angular Material input field.  Also, the button doesn't change heights when I change the height property to 100%.

I'm sure I am missing something simple.  Can anyone help?

```
<form>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>E-Mail</mat-label>
                    <input matInput placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                </mat-form-field>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Get Updates!</button>
</form>
```

[image: Angular Material Form]

Answer (score 2):

That should get the `input` & the `button` to get equal hight:

```
form {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
}
```

And the reason the input element wont style. Is because you are tying to style an element in `mat-form-field` which is a different component. If you want to style inner component elements like in your case, you should do like so:

```
:host ::ng-deep mat-form-field {
   input {
       background-color:#fff;
   }
}
```

Comment: Using flex did fix the height issue.  However, the background is still not showing correctly.  Your posted code with :host ::ng-deep didn't work with the .input subsection.  However, if I moved input up (see below) it does indeed color the input white.  Unfortunately, this doesn't look correct as the padding/margin of the input box aren't showing white.  I am playing around with the mat-form-field-wrapper with your approach but not having luck yet. 

 :host ::ng-deep mat-form-field input {
        background-color:#fff;
 }

Comment: I see why its because I made by mistake `.input` as the selector (I just corrected it) instead of `input`, (and you probably need `.scss`  to use it the way I wrote in my answer on `.css` you need to do it the way you did). I'm glad you solved it.